# How to remove strings which extends original string from JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, algorithm

I have the following array:
`['total.color.violet', 'total.color.violet.truefont', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.red.circle', 'total.color.red.circle.elefant', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow', 'total.color.yellow.dotted']`. As we can see all the strings have constant part **total.color** and the variable part.
I need to get the next result: `['total.color.violet', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow']` - to remove strings which have more than 'third level' complexity and leave string only with 'second level' complexity.
Please, look throw this algorithm and give me any tips, if it is possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please provide a sample output you would like.

Comment: @TwittorDrive I added an answer with a single line of code. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Just use `'level1.level2.level3'.split('.')` to break it into an array that is separated by `.`.

You can easily remove duplicated items (case sensitive) by using Set() and then converting it back into an array.

```js
let values = ['total.color.violet', 'total.color.violet.truefont', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.red.circle', 'total.color.red.circle.elefant', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow', 'total.color.yellow.dotted'];

let level123 = [];
let colorsOnly = [];
for(let value of values){
    // Get each level (seperated by '.')
    let level = value.split('.');
    
    // Add each level (1-3)
    level123.push(`${level[0]}.${level[1]}.${level[2]}`);
    
    // Add only the colors
    colorsOnly.push(level[2]);
}

// Remove duplication
level123 = [...new Set(level123)];
colorsOnly = [...new Set(colorsOnly)]

// Show the newly formatted values
console.log("Levels 1-3: ", level123);
console.log("Colors only: ", colorsOnly);
```

Comment: That isn't the output the OP wants.

Comment: @Andy Ah, was difficult to understand exactly what he was asking for. After re-reading... now I believe he is only wanting the colors out of the string? I've added a `colorsOnly` value — getting what he's asked for.

Comment: `['total.color.violet', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow']` without duplication.

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove duplicates using `Set()`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be use filter based on the length of calling split on each word.
[javascript split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

One easy method would be to loop through the array and remove the "`total.color`". Portion from each string using slicing or the replace method. Then, on a second loop through, if the string contains a "."
There are more than 3 levels:

- [String Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [Sting includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- A more complicated method would be to use a regex

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple case of 'count the dots'.

Here I'm using a regular expression to determine the number of occurrences of `.` within the string.  'g' flag returns all occurrences in the string.

`match` can return null in the case of no matches, so the `|| []` ensures that there is an array of zero length, so that we can access the property `length`.

All entries with 2 or less dots is retained in the filtered array.

```js
let values = ['total.color.violet', 'total.color.violet.truefont', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.red.circle', 'total.color.red.circle.elefant', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow', 'total.color.yellow.dotted']

const output = values
    .filter(value => (value.match(/\./g) || []).length <= 2)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [a Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove the dupes, and [a regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to find the string using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
const arr=['total.color.violet','total.color.violet.truefont','total.color.red','total.color.red.circle','total.color.red.circle.elefant','total.color.blue','total.color.yellow','total.color.yellow.dotted'];

const set = new Set();
const re = /^total.color.[a-z]+/;

for (const str of arr) {
  set.add(str.match(re)[0]);
}

console.log([...set]);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by first finding those elements that start with your prefix, then for each one, slice off the prefix (plus an additional `'.'`), split it at every `','`, take the first result and append it to the prefix (again, plus `'.'`.)  Then we take the unique set of these by wrapping the results in a Set and turning that back into an array.  It might look like this:

```js
const nextLevel = (strings, prefix) => [...new Set (
  strings .filter (s => s .startsWith (prefix + '.')) 
          .map (s => prefix + '.' + s .slice (prefix .length + 1) .split ('.') [0])
)]

const strings1 = ['total.color.violet', 'total.color.violet.truefont', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.red.circle', 'total.color.red.circle.elefant', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow', 'total.color.yellow.dotted']
const prefix1 = 'total.color'
console .log (nextLevel (strings1, prefix1))

const strings2 = ['telex.fast', 'telex.fast.line.hope', 'total.fast.ring', 'telex.slow', 'total.slow.motion']
const prefix2 = 'telex'
console .log (nextLevel (strings2, prefix2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

---

An interesting alternative would be to not supply the prefix as an initial parameter, but to  extract it from the strings directly.  We could do it like this:

```js
const leveled = (ss, prefix = ss .reduce ((x, y, _, __, [a, b] = y .length < x .length ? [x, y] : [y, x]) => 
  a .slice (0, [...a] .findIndex ((_, i) => a [i] !== b [i]))
)) => [...new Set (ss .map (s => s .substring (prefix .length) .split ('.') [0]))] .map (s => prefix + s)

const input1 = ['total.color.violet', 'total.color.violet.truefont', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.red.circle', 'total.color.red.circle.elefant', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow', 'total.color.yellow.dotted']
console .log (leveled (input1))

const input2 =['telex.fast', 'telex.fast.line.hope', 'total.fast.ring', 'telex.slow', 'total.slow.motion']
console .log (leveled (input2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But this would not capture that `telex` example in the same manner as the above, since it considers all levels, and there is no common prefix.  Where the example above gave us `['telex.fast', 'telex.slow']`, this one would give us `['telex', 'total']`.  Which one is more appropriate depends on your needs.

We should also note that as this technique uses `reduce` without an initial value, it will not work on an empty list of values.

Finally, this version should probably be cleaned up, with helper functions extracted.  I would probably prefer to write it this way:

```js
const sharedPrefix = (a, b) => a.length < b .length 
  ? sharedPrefix (b, a) 
  : a .slice (0, [...a] .findIndex ((_, i) => a [i] !== b [i]))

const commonPrefix = (ss) => ss .reduce (sharedPrefix)

const leveled = (ss, prefix = commonPrefix (ss)) =>
  [...new Set (ss .map (s => s .substring (prefix .length) .split ('.') [0]))] .map (s => prefix + s)
```

(This is barely tested.)

Comment: Scott Sauyet, wow cool resolution with reduce method, thanks. I will get it after testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that with a single line of code by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [
  'total.color.violet',
  'total.color.violet.truefont',
  'total.color.red',
  'total.color.red.circle',
  'total.color.red.circle.elefant',
  'total.color.blue',
  'total.color.yellow',
  'total.color.yellow.dotted'
];

const prefix = 'total.color';

const res = arr.filter(item => item.indexOf(prefix) === 0).filter(item => item.split('.').length === 3);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the dots.
Here I'm not using regex to determine the number of `.`

```js
const arr = ['total.color.violet', 'total.color.violet.truefont', 'total.color.red', 'total.color.red.circle', 'total.color.red.circle.elefant', 'total.color.blue', 'total.color.yellow', 'total.color.yellow.dotted'];

const dotCount = (str) => {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        count += (str[i] == '.' ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return count;
}

const filterArray = (arr) => {
    let filtered = []
    arr.forEach(el => {
        if (dotCount(el) <= 2) {
            filtered.push(el);
        }
    })
    
    return filtered;
}

console.log(filterArray(arr))
```